# How do I trap for errors in LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql

I am using LOAD DATA INFILE to import a large csv file, and I crash whenerver one of the fields has an extra apostrophe ie the name O'Brien

Answer (score 0):

Crash how? Are you running the load query from within a PHP script? In that case:

```
$res = mysql_query("LOAD DATA ....")
if ($res === FALSE) {
    ... load failed ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape apostrophe (') and double quotes (") of you query statements with a backslash '\'.

For instance:

str_replace("'","\'")

str_replace('\"','\\'')